# WindowManager get focus?

Tags: android

I have a window manager set up and it has the flag FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE which means it will not get the focus of key events. Is there anyway to reverse this upon a click for example? For example, if I click on a button, I want the window to be clickable. How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply update the window manager with the new parameters.

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, 
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //remove FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
        params.flags = params.flags & ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;

        //update the view
        windowManager.updateViewLayout(view, params);
    }
});
```