# How to get focusable in a windowmanager view

Tags: android, view, window-managers

I use the WindowManager to create a view and add the view to the screen,but I cannot get the view focusable.I think I set the WindowManager.LayoutParams correct.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    pushView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.push, null);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    cancelBtn = (Button) pushView.findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);
    windowManager = getWindowManager();
    handler = new MyHandler();

    pushView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            System.out.println("onclick");
            windowManager.removeView(pushView);
        }
    });


    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, 
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN | 
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
            params.y = 0;
            params.x = 0;

            windowManager.addView(pushView, params);

            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0x123);
                }
            }, 5000);

        }
    });

}
```

I want get the pushView'focusable to handle view's event.This problem has troubled me for a long time.Who can help me...

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to remove the `FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` flag:

```
params.flags = params.flags & ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
```

Comment: I'm so sorry,it's useless.Can you descripte a detail,thank you.

Comment: Seems like he can't

Comment: For details, visit this solution


 https://stackoverflow.com/a/18627981/11114671

Answer (score 1):

This is probably 4 years too late but have you tried using `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` instead of `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`.

The former doesn't seem to have the focus deprivation limiation

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the question.Because I use the `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`.
Window type: system overlay windows, which need to be displayed on top of everything else. These windows must not take input focus, or they will interfere with the keyguard. In multiuser systems shows only on the owning user's window.

So I cannot get the input focus.